# convert code from Python 2.x to 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a followup on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496762/code-changes-from-python-2-6-to-3-x), I am using the 2to3 tool as suggested by Senthil Kumaran

It seems to work well but it doesn't pick up this part:

```
raise LexError,("%s:%d: Rule '%s' returned an unknown token type '%s'" % (
    func.func_code.co_filename, func.func_code.co_firstlineno,
    func.__name__, newtok.type),lexdata[lexpos:])
```

What should this look like in 3.2 ?

**EDIT:** the changes from the answer below are good, 2to3 now seems to work ok. Howevery in the setup.py build I now get the error below, see my new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497951/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the comma after LexError. That works in both Python 2 and Python 3.

In Python 2 there was a rarely used syntax to raise exceptions like this:

```
raise ExceptionClass, "The message string"
```

This is the one used here, but for some reason, maybe since there is a parenthesis around the message string (according to Senthils tests, it's the line break in the parenthesis that does it), 2to3 misses the change into the much better:

```
raise ExceptionClass("The message string")
```

So it should look like this (in Python 2)

```
message = "%s:%d: Rule '%s' returned an unknown token type '%s'" % (
           func.func_code.co_filename, func.func_code.co_firstlineno,
           func.__name__, newtok.type),lexdata[lexpos:])
raise LexError(message)
```

Because formatting that message on the same line as the raise is fugly. :-)
Then in addition func_code has been renamed, so in Python 3 there are more changes. But with the above change 2to3 should work correctly.

Comment: The suggested changes are ok, 2to3 picks it up now but I get an error in the build (after the 2to3 changes). I edited my question.

Comment: @Remko: Which made it a different question. You should remove the edit and make a new question instead. Except that the new question is a duplicate. :) http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Attempted+relative+import+in+non-package

Comment: Created new question, if it is a duplicate please point me since I found several questions with the same error but wasn't able to get a solution from them.

Comment: Accepted this answer as it was the most complete

Answer (score 11):

The `func_code` attribute of functions has been renamed to `__code__`, so try

```
func.__code__.co_filename, func.__code__.co_firstlineno,
```

as the second line of your code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

What problem are you getting? 2to3 seems to translate it for me fine.

```
-    raise LexError,("%s:%d: Rule '%s' returned an unknown token type '%s'" % (func.func_code.co_filename,func.func_code.co_firstlineno,func.__name__,newtok.type),lexdata[lexpos:])
+    raise LexError("%s:%d: Rule '%s' returned an unknown token type '%s'" % (func.__code__.co_filename,func.__code__.co_firstlineno,func.__name__,newtok.type),lexdata[lexpos:])
```

Comment: Oh I see. Quite possibly a bug with 2to3.

Comment: Yeah, covering all weird cases with 2to3 can be a pain.

Comment: Yes it seems to be the line break